How to hook Doctrine validation into EasyAdmin
I understand how to add validation for Doctrine 3 entities, but from what I can tell, EasyAdmin is supposed to display that validation as part of its forms. Currently it just throws exceptions which are handled in the debug exception interface. How do I get it to wire up automatically? I can't find any documentation on the topic for Doctrine 3 + Symfony 7 + EasyAdmin 4.

#[ORM\Column(type: Types::DATE_MUTABLE, nullable: true)]
#[Assert\GreaterThan('tomorrow', message: 'TOO SOON')]
private ?\DateTimeInterface $next_payment_date = null;

Turns out you can do it with the Doctrine asserts. Still can't find any instruction on how to do more complex validation and add custom errors.
